# Excel VBA Code to Generate Sequential number with a Prefix

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small issue with my code. The code is below.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range, n As Long
Dim pType As String
Dim oMax As Long
Set Rng = Range(Range("E1"), Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Const StartNum = 1
    pType = Me.TextBox1.Value
if pType = vbNullString Then MsgBox "Please Select Option from Combo Box": Exit Sub


With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
For Each Dn In Rng
If Left(Dn.Value, 1) = pType Then
If Not .Exists(Dn.Value) Then
   .Add Dn.Value, Mid(Dn, 2)
oMax = Application.Max(.Item(Dn.Value), Mid(Dn, 2))
Else
    MsgBox "Number Exists:-" & Dn.Value
End If
End If
Next
If .Count = 0 Then
Range("E" & Rng.Count + 1) = pType & StartNum
Else
Range("E" & Rng.Count + 1) = pType & oMax + 1
End If
End With

End Sub
```

This code starts generating number from the 2nd row while i want the starting row should be 5. i tried to change the range value from E1 to E5 but it didn't work.

Kindly review and suggest the modification.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the below line

```
Range("E" & Rng.Count + 1) = pType & StartNum
```

to

```
Range("E" & Rng.Count + 4) = pType & StartNum
```

Comment: If i do this then its starts generating after four rows.

Comment: As per your question, you want the seq numbers from 5th row. This code will start generating the numbers from row 5 (E5)

Comment: If you are expecting a different result, please explain it in your question.